# I need to get all browser info like OS, Operating system, IP, City etc?

Tags: php, browser

I need exactly all information as in following url

http://thetutlage.com/demo/tut_analytics/

Can any one tell me the solution for this in php ?

Answer (score 5):

You can get a lot of info from the [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) global-array.

IP Address: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Browser/OS/versions: `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`

To get the City or some other geo information from the IP, Google for "geo IP".
Quick note about geo IP: it's not waterproof. It's a managed database with IP addresses and their location. New IP ranges, or moved ("Second hand") IP addresses might not be (or not correct) in the database. Especially IPv6 for example.

Answer (score 1):

The $_SERVER superglobal is your solution -> http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: You should add examples of how to do it to improve your answer and make it so it's not just a link to how. ^^

Comment: Note taken. Thank you :) Other fellows have already given examples

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Maxmind geoip database to get City/Country/Region:
http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/downloadable

Answer (score 0):

Look at php functions.

for IP Address

```
  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

similarly you have all other functions to get those values
refer

```
$_SERVER
```

variable.

Answer (score 0):

Getting all information from one source is not possible.

You can use this library for getting information regarding user Operation system and its version and other details

https://github.com/GaretJax/phpbrowscap/.

You can get user device info using :

```
$browscap = @new Browscap(sys_get_temp_dir());
$device_details = $browscap->getBrowser();
```

The above will output :

```
stdClass Object
(
    [browser_name] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 \(.*windows nt 6\.2.*wow64.*\) applewebkit/.* \(khtml, like gecko\).*chrome/26\..*safari/.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (*Windows NT 6.2*WOW64*) AppleWebKit/* (KHTML, like Gecko)*Chrome/26.*Safari/*
    [Parent] => Chrome 26.0
    [Platform] => Win8
    [Platform_Version] => 6.2
    [Win32] => 
    [Win64] => 1
    [Comment] => Chrome 26.0
    [Browser] => Chrome
    [Version] => 26.0
    [MajorVer] => 26
    [MinorVer] => 0
    [Beta] => 1
    [Frames] => 1
    [IFrames] => 1
    [Tables] => 1
    [Cookies] => 1
    [JavaScript] => 1
    [JavaApplets] => 1
    [CssVersion] => 3
    [Alpha] => 
    [Win16] => 
    [BackgroundSounds] => 
    [VBScript] => 
    [ActiveXControls] => 
    [isMobileDevice] => 
    [isSyndicationReader] => 
    [Crawler] => 
)
```

PHP has an inbuilt function `get_browser()` which will do the same. You have to browscap ini directive then.

If you want to get the user IP, then you can get it from the $_SERVER variable

```
$ip_address = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

If you want to know the user city, country etc then you can use the IP you got from the `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` to get those . You can use these:

- http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity
- http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=users_Ip
- http://smart-ip.net/geoip-api
- http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite
- http://briancray.com/posts/find-web-visitors-location-javascript-google-api/

Hope these helps you :)

Comment: Thanks for this info, I have tried this solution locally and its working fine after installing browscap ext and now when i tried to use this on my client site, it says same warning "Warning: get_browser(): browscap ini directive not set in /home/mytrklin/public_html/get-visitor.php on line 10" so i need to know how to install browscap.ini on cpanel ? If you can tell me it would be really great

Comment: @NaveedMetlo I think since you are using cpanel for hosting and all, I am not sure whether it will be possible for you. If you can try with the browscap library (https://github.com/GaretJax/phpbrowscap/) , it can give you the info with out directive setting. Can you try that instead of get_browser

Comment: @ Sabari. I just get enabled through cpanel and they installed and now i can get all browser info which is what i wanted so will try your solution if i need some thing same. Thanks Sabari...

Answer (score 0):

You can not get all the information in one place.

Some information can be found in `$_SERVER` including the clients browser.
 You can use this information to get more details about the client:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
```

The above example will output something similar to:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7) Gecko/20040803 Firefox/0.9.3

Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 9
    [cssversion] => 2
    [frames] => 1
    [iframes] => 1
    [tables] => 1
    [cookies] => 1
    [backgroundsounds] =>
    [vbscript] =>
    [javascript] => 1
    [javaapplets] => 1
    ...
)
```

Some informations like the users location are harder to get.

To get the users location you can try to use a geoip lib or use ajax and sniff out the data via javascript.

Both approaches are covered in depth on SO so I`ll just point you to the search and wich you good luck ;)